# How can I submit unchecked html checkboxes without Stripes tags?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, stripes

I am trying to use javascript client templates alongside the Stripes framework. This means I am unable to use the stripes form tag library, which by default injects a hidden encrypted field that stripes uses to determine what checkboxes were rendered along with the form, so it can determine what checkboxes have been unchecked if they weren't passed as a form parameter.

Its a great burden to include this encrypted hidden field alongside all my forms without being able to use a tag library, so I'm looking for a global solution. What I've come up with is intercepting forms before they are submitted, changing the value of any unchecked checkboxes to false, and checking them so they are sent to the server. This works with the side effect of having the user see all his unchecked options brielfy checked again before the form submission is finished. Is there any way to hide the checked animation but still have the form submit the values?

Here is my current solution:

```
$("body").delegate("form", "submit", function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)', $this).each(function() { 
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('value', 'false');
        $this.attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
});
```

Comment: Well the solution came to me to simply append a hidden field instead:

    $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)', $this).each(function() { 
   $('<input>').attr('type','hidden').attr('name', $(this).attr('name')).attr('value','false').appendTo($this);
  });

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // This :unchecked custom selecor was created by me.
        //http://nanoquantumtech.blogspot.in/2012/03/unchecked-selector-matches-all-elements.html
        $.extend($.expr[':'], {
            unchecked: function (obj) {
                return ((obj.type == 'checkbox' || obj.type == 'radio') && !$(obj).is(':checked'));
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#checkBoxList').find(':checked').addClass('vechicalChecked');

            $('#btnCheckedToUncheckedValues').click(function () {
                var checkedToUncheckedValues = [];

                $('#checkBoxList').find('.vechicalChecked:unchecked').each(function () {
                    checkedToUncheckedValues.push($(this).val());
                });

                alert('Checked To Unchecked Values Are : ' + (checkedToUncheckedValues.length == 0 ? 'none' : checkedToUncheckedValues.join(',')));
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="checkBoxList">
        <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="Vechical" checked="checked" />0<br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Vechical" />1<br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="Vechical" checked="checked" />2<br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="Vechical" checked="checked" />3<br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="Vechical" />4<br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="Vechical" checked="checked" />5<br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="6" name="Vechical" />6<br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="7" name="Vechical" />7<br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="8" name="Vechical" checked="checked" />8<br />
        <input type="button" id="btnCheckedToUncheckedValues" value="checked To Unchecked Values" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: // This :unchecked custom selecor was created by me.
        //http://nanoquantumtech.blogspot.in/2012/03/unchecked-selector-matches-all-elements.html